# Remove class when scrolling up or down

Tags: jquery, scroll, removeclass, mouseenter

What I would like to achieve is to remove specific class or hide classes when scrolling up or down (to avoid lag).
I have the following code:

```
var $div = $('#div');   
$div.on('mouseenter', '.box', function() {
    $(this).find('span.category').addClass('bg-category');
    $(this).find('.post-options').show();
});
```

and // on leave:

```
$div.on('mouseleave', '.box', function() {
    $(this).find('span.category').removeClass('bg-category');
    $(this).find('.post-options').hide();
});
```

Basically, I have a lot of images, and when scrolling whilst mouse is hovered on .box it lags the page significantly. So what I would like to achieve is to remove these class not only on 'mouseleave' but also when scrolling up or down the page.

Similar to google+ has when scrolling on the cards of content you'll notice on mouse hover the links light up but once scrolling they are removed. eg: https://plus.google.com/communities/100354381402619402956

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;
$(window).scroll(function(event){
   var st = $(this).scrollTop();
   if (st > lastScrollTop){
   // downscroll code
      $("#div").find('.post-options').show();
      $(".box").delay(800).addClass('dummyclass');
   } else {
  // upscroll code
      $("#div").find('.post-options').hide();
      $(".box").delay(800).addClass('dummyclass');
  }
lastScrollTop = st;
});
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, yes that actually works but I forgot to mention, if the user stops scrolling I would like the class to be added without having to re-hover on .box if you know what I mean?

Comment: @Emanradin : What is the name of the class you need to be added when user stops scrolling? And where do you want it added?

Comment: the class is called 'bg-category' and it will be located under '.box' > span.category > bg-category. I'm not too sure if 'mouseover' would work?